# sparse lil_matrix cannot assign data

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

When trying to directly set the `data` attribute of a sparse `lil_matrix`, I encounter very unexpected behavior. Can someone explain what is going on in the following simple example?

My particular use case is I want to set the row modulo 2; i.e. in dense-matrix-speak I just want to do `matrix[0] %= 2`.

```
from scipy import sparse
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

matrix = sparse.rand(10**3,10**3).tolil()
num_entries = len(matrix[0].data[0])
print num_entries
# 9

# this throws no errors...
matrix[0].data[0] = [2]*num_entries
# but does nothing!

assert (np.array(matrix[0].data) == 2).all() # FAILS

# in fact nothing can be done to alter .data directly...
matrix[0].data[0].pop() # returns the last float from the row
# but does not actually pop it from the row!
assert (len(matrix[0].data[0]) == num_entries-1) # FAILS
```

Comment: What's the value of `num_entries`?  I'm guessing `0`.  `matrix.data` is a list of lists, and `matrix.data[0]` is the first of those.  It could well be empty.

Comment: I added it in the code above -- but num_entries is 9. matrix.data is actually a numpy.array of python objects which are lists.

Comment: So `matrix[i].data[0] == matrix.data[i]` is true for all `i`, but same is not true when compared with the `is` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what kind of object `matrix[0]` is, but I think you mean to drop the indexing on `matrix` and only keep it on `data`:

```
num_entries = len(matrix.data[0])
matrix.data[0] = [2]*num_entries
```

Comment: This solved it, thanks! I think the _reason_ is that `matrix[0]` is actually making a copy of the first row and putting it in a new matrix. So when I was setting that data, I wasn't setting `matrix`.

Answer (score 0):

@vlsd found the bug, but I'm adding this to say more.

The issue with the code I posted is that I assign (throughout) to `matrix[0].data`. The problem is that `matrix[0]` doesn't work the same as dense-arrays; it's not simply pointing to the same object, but making a new object (I think). So assigning data to this new object is fine, but it just doesn't affect `matrix`. That's the problem.

So the following code works fine:

```
matrix.data[0] = [2]*num_entries
assert (np.array(matrix.data[0]) == 2).all() # passes
matrix.data[0].pop()
assert (len(matrix.data[0]) == num_entries-1) # passes
```

**NB** That popping from the list is generally a bad idea as this probably ruins the integrity of the sparse-matrix. But this was just to demo. And it now makes sense.